# Extending Number.prototype in javascript and the Math object?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, methods

I've always wondered why Javascript has the global Math object instead of giving numbers their own methods. Is there a good reason for it?

Also are there any drawbacks (other than efficiency) to doing something like this?:

```
Number.prototype.round = function(){
    return Math.round(this);
};
```

Just to make clear, I understand that constants like π need somewhere and functions that are applied on more than one number like min/max. The question was mainly concerning methods which only effect a single number such as round, abs, sin, pow, etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason for the `Math` object is simple: "because Java does it". Not the best of reasons, but here we are. I guess things made more sense back then, before Douglas Crockford started his campaign to suppress half the language*. Originally you were "allowed", or meant, to do things like this:

```
with (Math) {
  var n = min( round(a) * round(b), sqrt(c) );
  var result = exp( n + d );
}
```

The drawback to extending `Number.prototype` is that someone else might do the same thing. Or worse, for example, define `Number.prototype.round` as a *symmetrical* rounding function.

If you are looking for ways to make your life easier, why stop there? Why not simply include `Math` functions as global functions?

```
var m = 'abs acos asin atan atan2 ceil cos exp floor log max min ' +
        'pow random round sin sqrt tan PI').split(' ');
for (var i=0,l=m.length; i<l; i++) {
  window[ m[i] ] = Math[ m[i] ];
}
```

This will drop all the math functions into the global scope, effectively allowing you to stop typing "Math." Ask yourself: Is there any real difference between extending `Number` and extending `window` with these functions?

* Before you flame me: The Crockford comment is not meant to be taken too seriously. I do agree with him that `with` is very dangerous in an implicit global environment.

Answer (score 24):

There is no drawback in extending `Number.prototype` other than confusing other people. What's the point? What is better in using `value.round()` instead of `Math.round(value)`?

There are several good reasons for the `Math` object:

1. It works for non-numbers, too: `Math.round("5")` works whereas `value.round()` won't work when value is a string (for example, the value of a textbox)
2. Some members of the Math object don't belong to a "primary" number value, like `Math.min()` or `Math.max()`. Or do you want to use it like `a.max(b)`?
3. Other members are global and do not belong to a specialized number. Examples are constants like `Math.PI` or the function `Math.random()`.

Comment: Good observations, +1. I'm wondering though, why Douglas Crockford said JavaScript made a mistake when borrowing the Math object from Java.

Comment: @Ferdinand: I was never planning on using anything like "a.max('5')". Some of the functions and constants belong in the Math object (I'll update my post to make that clear). The ones that are applied on the number alone is what I'm interested in. That you can use strings is a good point though.

Comment: There are also performance considerations -- value.anything requires boxing the value - eg. converting value into an object.  (It is possible to avoid this occasionally, but not in any of your likely use cases)

Comment: I personally see point 1 above as a very helpful feature. Trying to round a string _should_ throw an error. @olliej very good point about value boxing!

Answer (score 18):

Try doing `123.round();`

Your javascript console will throw a few hundred of errors to your eyes :P, nah ...

You can do:

`Number.prototype.x` then: `(123).x();` but never `123.x();`

Comment: I've always wondered why you couldn't do 123.method(). I know it's easier not to allow it because of floats, however I think ruby allows the syntax and it would make everything easier!

Comment: Yes, either `123..round()` or `(123).round()` will work. `123..round() === 123.0.round()`

Comment: until you started using framework liks Vue, than you'll see `Error compiling template:`

Answer (score 1):

I think Math is more than set of Number methods. It's usage wider. Say, using NumberVariable.PI can be confusing. Same with random numbers generation.

Also I think extending number is OK, because it's the part of JS nature. Maybe someone will correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: You can pretty much extend anything but the Array object. It's the Array object where extending get's annoying because you then can't do a simpel for..in loop (yes I know you can use a for() but that just looks so ugly.

Comment: @Pim Jager: you shouldn't be using for...in for arrays anyway - that's meant for objects. Which is why the *real* no-no is extending Object.prototype...

Comment: You can extend if your javascript version supports Object.defineProperty. There's the option enumerable:false

Answer (score 1):

I believe calling it this way works as well, since Number's prototype functions work just like every other Object's prototype functions do:

```
5.5["round"]();
//should return 6
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the conversation on whether its a good idea or not aside, you can do this fine.

You can do 123.x() but the interpreter for js is broken (as it doesn't interpret the dot as a message dispatch)

Weirdly, you can use 123 .x() (with a space between the number and the dot) instead, and it'll work.

123..also works but that's because you've effectively made a decimal and then dispatching to it

> (typeof 123.) === 'number')  // true

Try:

> Number.prototype.times = function(other) { return this * other }; 3 .times(5);

in the console.

Comment: It's not "broken" when it's working the way it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

My view on this is that if you do the proper checks as to not overwrite native functionality, name with understanding of native naming standards and it makes your code more readable and manageable, then make your code comfortable and convenient.

```
if (Number.prototype.round == null)
    Number.prototype.round = function() { return Math.round(this); }
```

AS for using this, because of the nature of javascript, I believe the best way to do this is by:

- Wrapping the number in a variable instead of a simple static value (Most often the case)

  - nNum.round();
- Wrapping the simple static value in parentheses :

  - (123).round();
- Calling using square bracket notation

  - 123["round"].call();

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Number.prototype.round = function() {
    return Math.round(this.valueOf());
};
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_num.asp