# Add a rounding method to Number.prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype, rounding, polyfills

How can I simplify rounding in JavaScript? I wish that I could do it in a more elegantly in an object-oriented manner. The method toFixed works well, but does not have backward rounding and it also returns a string and not a number.

```
pi.toFixed(2).valueOf();
// 3.14
```

As it is, rounding is a bit of a tangle because I have to use:

```
pi = Math.round(pi * 100) / 100;
// 3.14
```

It would be much nicer instead just to stick a method to the end of a variable, such as:

```
pi.round(2);
// 3.1r
```

Comment: The two things are not equivalent. Do you expect pi.round(2) to *mutate* the number? That's impossible, since numbers are immutable.

Comment: What's wrong with `pi.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: Mutability: All I can do is nod and smile, pretending to know what that means. For what it is worth, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#JavaScript) says: "Custom classes are generally mutable. To simulate immutability in a class, one should set immutable properties to prototype of object."

Comment: toFixed: There is nothing wrong with it. To be honest, I didn't know about it. In any event, it makes a string and you have to convert it back into a number with valueOf(). Also, it does not perform backward rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Extend Number.prototype. Numbers in Javascript are a data type that is associated with the built-in object "Number." Add the following polyfill block:

```
if (!Number.prototype.round) {
    Number.prototype.round = function (decimals) {
        if (typeof decimals === 'undefined') {
            decimals = 0;
        }
        return Math.round(
            this * Math.pow(10, decimals)
        ) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
    };
}
```

Anywhere after this, you can round numbers by sticking .round() to the end of them. It has one optional parameter that determines the number of decimals. For example:

```
pi.round(2);
```

You can also use backward rounding with negative numbers such as:

```
x = 54321;
x.round(-4);
// 50000
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2n2fbmq/

Related:

- [Javascript Convert numbers to different formats or string alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783543/javascript-convert-numbers-to-different-formats-or-string-alternative/7783771#7783771)
- [Extending Number.prototype in javascript and the Math object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622374/extending-number-prototype-in-javascript-and-the-math-object)
- [Integer prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394841/integer-prototype)

Comment: What is `Number.prototype.contains`?

Comment: The method 'contains' returns true or false. It is a way of checking that Number.prototype is not already being used.

Comment: I am not an advanced programmer, and just now starting to wrap my mind around prototyping. I was so proud of this one that I decided to show it off. If I am doing something wrong, please kick me and then explain why.

Comment: `Number.prototype.contains` is undefined in my Chrome.

Comment: Seems to be working as it should. In an 'if' statement, undefined resolves to 'false.' In this case, false will allow the block in the if statement to execute because of the use of the exclamation point.

Comment: I still don't understand. Under what circumstances would it ever be defined? What do you mean by "Number.prototype is not already being used"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65275/discussion-between-heyzeuss-and-barmar).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should use Number.prototype.round instead of Number.prototype.contains.

Answer (score 0):

First off: **Don't do it**

Extending builtin prototypes is generally frowned upon as new standards may break your code. Libraries that extended builtin prototypes have caused trouble in the past.

However if you really want to and accept the risk, it should be relatively safe if you add a prefix that is unlikely to be adopted by any standard.

```js
if (!Number.prototype.$round) {
  Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, '$round', {
    value(precision) {
      return +this.toFixed(precision)
    },
  })
}

(123.456789).$round(2) // 123.45
```

By prefixing the property with `$`, your code will continue to work if `Number#round()` is standardized.

I use `Object.defineProperty` instead of `=` as it makes the property non-enumerable by default. Meaning it won't show up in `for..in`-loops.